# Angular Store like Dynamic Route

Tags: angular, angular-router

I'm looking for a solution for repeating parts in the urls for Angular(5+).

Something like store categories and products within.

Ids are really UUID, but for brevity´s sake I'll use integers here.

Lets say something like:

- TV ( Category, id: 2 )

  - Samsung ( Category, id: 3 )

    - Some TV ( Product, id: 1 )
- Personal Devices ( Category, id: 4 )

  - Mobile phones ( Category, id: 5 )

    - Samsung ( Category, id: 7 )

      - Some Phone ( Product, id: 2 )

I'd like to build following URLs.

`/TV/` ( Category listing page )
`/TV/Samsung/` ( Category listing page )
`/TV/Samsung/Some TV-1` ( product view page )
`/Personal Devices/` ( Category listing page )
`/Personal Devices/Mobile Phones/` ( Category listing page )
`/Personal Devices/Mobile Phones/Samsung/` ( Category listing page )
`/Personal Devices/Mobile Phones/Samsung/Some Phone-2` ( product view page )

I can fetch all product categories and arrange those into a tree with parentId reference. Note Samsung is just a category with the same name as the other one.

The tricky part here is that before I get the categories from the server I have no idea of the category depths or product places in them.

No, route like `/:product-:product-id` is not an option.

So routes could be

    `/:categoryName/
    /:categoryName/:categoryName/
    /:categoryName/:productName-:productId`

Or explained with kind of a regex:

- n times categoryName for CategoryComponent
- n times categoryName and productName & id for ProductComponent

`/(:categoryName/)+ for CategoryComponent
    /:categoryName/(:categoryName/)*:productName-:productId for ProductComponent`

Custom route [matcher](https://angular.io/api/router/UrlMatcher) is a good option for ProductComponent with guard/resolve checking for not found but how to handle those nested categories?

How would you handle this, by using custom matchers or is there something else I could use?

Comment: have you figured out solution @MTJ?

Comment: I used custom route matcher and loading / validation in the component.

I really haven't had a need for this lately while doing enterprise applications, so I haven't checked if this can be accomplished with current angular easier.

Comment: Thanks for reply. In my case I use UrlMatcher to determinate that url is for list component or detail component, then in component make api request, server will have to check which category, brand...